# Customize range input to indicate progress

Tags: javascript, html, input, styles, range

I have a `range input`:

```
<input id="progress" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" title="">
```

[image]

Now i want to add a `color` to the left side of the icon.

Kinda like how the `audio tag` looks in `Chrome`:

[image: audio tag]

But I absolutely do not know how to do it.

Or if it's even possible to do it with `css` or `javascript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this using Jquery:

```js
$('input[type="range"]').change(function () {
    var val = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min')) / ($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));
    
    $(this).css('background-image',
                '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
                + 'color-stop(' + val + ', #000080), '
                + 'color-stop(' + val + ', #C5C5C5)'
                + ')'
                );
});
```

```css
input[type="range"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0.15, #000080),
        color-stop(0.15, #C5C5C5)
    );
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="15">
```